estimation of coefficients in power series substitution
Let $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n$ be a formal power series of $\mathbb R[[z]$ and $g(z)=\sum_{n\ge1}b_nz^n$ be an another formal power series of $\mathbb R[[z]]$. Since $\mathrm{val}_z(g(z))>0$, $g(z)$ is substituable in $f(z)$ forming a new formal power series $h(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}c_nz^n$ of $\mathbb R[[z]]$. Suppose that for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$, $|b_n|=1$. For $n\in\mathbb N_0$, can one give a upper bound of $|c_n|$ in function of the $|a_j|$'s?
Thanks in advance for any answer
